# Multiple Colors/Images in a background + Content

Tags: html, css

I have designed a website in photoshop that I would like to actually develop. I modeled the website off of http://illinoisstate.edu. Basically, I want the top gradient header, the middle image, and the content floating over the top. I tried a few different ways with various css styles and position types, but I cant seem to get the effect right. I tried researching and even downloading the site to see how they did it, but no luck. Does anyone know how to achieve that effect?

This link http://dev.connectionsquad.com shows what I have. I want that nasty colored div to be over the background divs, but when you shrink the size of the window I want the background to disappear and only focus on the content.

Comment: Use Firebug to examine the website. Also paste some of your code in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a div inside the body tag that will contain your background (let's say, ). Position it with relative position and define it's width and min-height. Inside it, put the different effects you want using other divs. Posistion these divs using position.
Afterwards, create a second div inside body but outside the first div. Position it and put the content in this div.

It will look like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="background_wrapper">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="midle_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content_wrapper">
        More divs...
        content...
    </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT:**
Use position in CSS to adjust the first wrapper, the header, the image and the second wrapper. I personally would use position:relative for the content wrapper and position:absolute for the background wrapper

Comment: When I did what you said above, the content_wrapper is not over the background. It just sits below it and is not centered.

Comment: I figured it out. Using absolute positioning on the background wrapper allowed the content wrapper to sneak in.

Comment: Yes, you're right... I'm just checking what I wrote and I realized that I changed the names. The background wrapper should be absolute and the content wrapper should be relative. Sorry about the mistake, but I'm glad you figured it out and solved the prolem :D

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the 'image in the middle' is background image of body. They adjusted the y position of background image to 232px to offset it from top. For the floating effect, box-shadow specified for a div with id 'body'.

I'm not sure about the second part of your question. If you could elaborate what is meant by the 'colored div', that would help. I used firebug to peek inside the code and css. You might like to do that too, if you haven't tried already. Hope this helps.

Comment: That is just for the image then though, how did they add the top and bottom border to the image and if you zoom out, there is coloring to the side of it, so something else must be there? And how do you adjust the y position of a background image?